# How to get LiveAgent id

Tags: rest-api, liveagent

```
liveagent.showWhenOnline('5737F000000PCZJ', document.getElementById('btnId'));
```

In the above code, `5737F000000PCZJ` this Id has been used.

Can anyone please explain what is this number and how can we get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LiveChatButton object to get chat button id.

```
select id,MasterLabel  from LiveChatButton
```